# Why don't these except blocks in my discord.py bot run even when the errors raise?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot that renders fractals, but I want it to tell people if they made an error. The part with the except blocks is as follows:

```
        try:
            MAX_ITER = int(iters)
            def mandelbrot(c):
                z = complex(float(start[0]),float(start[1]))
                n = 0
                i = cmath.sqrt(-1)
                while abs(z) <= float(brakeoff) and n < MAX_ITER: # number here is the brakeoff
                    # main formula
                    z = z ** complex(float(power[0]),float(power[1])) + c
                    n += 1
                return n
        except ValueError:
            valueerror = discord.Embed(title = "`ValueError` occured. Did you enter a letter or word where there was numeric input?")
            valueerror.set_author(name = "Error", icon_url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/848700721113333780.png?v=1")
            await status.edit(content="", embed=valueerror)
        except IndexError:
            indexerror = discord.Embed(title = "`IndexError` occured. Did you forget one of the components to a multi-component input?")
            indexerror.set_author(name = "Error", icon_url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/848700721113333780.png?v=1")
            await status.edit(content="", embed=indexerror)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            zerodivisionerror = discord.Embed(title = "`ZeroDivisionError` occured. What did I say about how the negative and complex exponents are not supported yet?")
            zerodivisionerror.set_author(name = "Error", icon_url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/848700721113333780.png?v=1")
            await status.edit(content="", embed=zerodivisionerror)
        except Exception as error:
            error = discord.Embed(title = "An error occured that is not documented in this formula. Here is the error in python: ||" + str(error) + "||")
```

When an error raises, it goes in the terminal as usual. But the except block that corresponds to the error doesn't run; it doesn't post that embed explaining the error. I tried other ways of error handling and they worked even less. All the examples I saw used Discord errors, and not normal errors like the ones I put in my except blocks. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean "goes in the terminal as usual"? Is your program crashing and displaying a stack trace?

Comment: It just prints this into the terminal:

Ignoring exception in command fractal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\poohn\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Mandelbot\Mandelbot.py", line 322, in fractal
    m = mandelbrot(c)
  File "c:\Users\poohn\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Mandelbot\Mandelbot.py", line 290, in mandelbrot
    z = complex(float(start[0]),float(start[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you considered using [discordpy's error handlers](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) instead of python's `try-except` block?

Comment: @12944qwerty I think discord.py's error-handling functions always receive Discord-specific errors that inherit from `CommandError`, right? Would that be useful for handling (and differentiating between) ordinary exceptions that occur in the "internal" Python workings of a user-defined function like this?

Comment: I tried those, and they somehow made the errors not show up in the terminal, let alone post the embed. Are those only for discord (commands.) errors? Is there a way to do this with non-discord errors such as IndexError, ValueError, etc.? edit: Did not see CrazyChucky's post until now. Is there perhaps another type of error handler?

Comment: @CrazyChucky They can be used for normal exceptions. I'm pretty sure. It's always worked for me

Comment: What is `status`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown puts the function *definition* inside a `try` block, but does not actually *call* it. In other words, your `except` blocks will only be entered if there's a problem in *defining* the function itself. (If you'd like a refresher on the difference, Real Python has a pretty thorough [tutorial](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/).)

As the terminal output says, the error isn't occurring there, it's occurring in line 322 of your `Mandelbot.py` file: `m = mandelbrot(c)`. This is where you call the function. Presumably you *don't* have a `try`/`except` set up there. None of your code catches or does anything with the exception, so discord.py simply displays it in the terminal and goes on about its business.

What you probably want is something more along the lines of *defining* the function in one place:

```
MAX_ITER = int(iters)
def mandelbrot(c):
    z = complex(float(start[0]),float(start[1]))
    n = 0
    i = cmath.sqrt(-1)
    while abs(z) <= float(brakeoff) and n < MAX_ITER: # number here is the brakeoff
        # main formula
        z = z ** complex(float(power[0]),float(power[1])) + c
        n += 1
    return n
```

And then, wherever it is that you're *calling* it, wrap it in a `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    m = mandelbrot(c)
except ValueError:
    # (Respond to error)
except IndexError:
    # And so on...
```

This way, you'll catch any errors that occur when you actually *use* your function.

Comment: The status is not the bot's status, it is the message it sends when it says "calculating" or "saving" and I told it to edit that message to be the embed. I wrote "status = await ctx.send("Calculating ...")" in the line before the first line I put there. Also, what do you mean by set up a try/except on line 322?

Comment: @Deseptor Ah, I see. This sort of thing is why it's a good idea to make your example [complete and self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (even if it may be simplified down from your full code), so that we know what we're looking at. I've edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear where your `try`/`except` should go.

Comment: I figured it out now, but now the error moved to the next line. What's going on now?

Comment: Well if you put a `try:` before your function call, the function call is now on line 323, right? But if you're still seeing the stack trace output in your terminal, it means none of your `except` clauses caught the exception.

Comment: I mean the error didn't refer to "m = mandelbrot(c)" anymore but now it moved to the line after that BEFORE I put the try: and the except clauses. And how could it not catch it if it's a ValueError and there's one that catches that?

Comment: Honestly, at this point I'd just be making wilder and wilder guesses. Please take a good look at [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question. If you make your code both **complete** (can be copy/pasted and run as-is, sans the bot token) and **minimal** (you've removed all unnecessary detail that you can, while still encountering the problem), then I or others here will have a much better chance of actually helping you.